# how do you compute the constant, c, for the asymptotic runtimes of heapSort?

Tags: sorting, heap

I am trying to understand how to compute the constant, `c`, when given the data. Before showing the data, I will inform you that I have already graphed the data with a linear trend on Excel. I am still quite baffled as to what I should use to calculate `c`.

**Key question:** How do you find some `c` that makes `O(g(n))` true?

Expecting that you do not need to find `T(n)`. The graphs you create should be sufficient.

Data for HeapSort:

```
1           0
5           0
10          0
50          0
100         0
500         0
1000        0
5000        0
10,000      0.01
50,000      0.04
100,000     0.1
500,000     0.484
1,000,000   1.346
5,000,000   6.596667
10,000,000  14.854
```

Comment: I assume that "c" relates to the definition of big "O" notation. But please define "c" in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this sort of problem is solved by fitting the data to an expected function (such as t = cn + b, or t = cnlogn + b) using a least-squares method.  Assuming that the "c" you are requesting is the constant factor in front of the main term of your runtime, you will get c with that method.

The value of c will of course be dependent on the particular code that is running and the particular machine on which it is running.